Mysql is closing the connection on Ubuntu

Hi I built a MERN app (used mysql instead of MongoDB)

deployed it on the VPS (Ubuntu 24.04) everything seems okay but
when I try to check the logs of my backend using pm2 package it gives
me kind of weird picture: first it gives me errors and then seems it
is connected why is that? is my mysql really running or not


This is my db connection code


const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dbHost = "127.0.0.1";
const databaseConnection = () => {
  const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'Test',
    password: 'Iwillnottell', 
    database: 'Test',
  });
  db.connect(err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('MySQL Connected...');
  });
  return db; };
module.exports = databaseConnection();





Instead of using createConnection, use a Connection Pool. Connection pools are more efficient and automatically handle reconnects.
Update your databaseConnection.js file:
// databaseConnection.js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const dbHost = "127.0.0.1";

const databaseConnection = () => {
  const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: dbHost,
    user: 'Test',
    password: 'Iwillnottell',
    database: 'Test',
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10, // Adjust this according to your needs
    queueLimit: 0
  });

  db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database Connection Error:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Successfully connected to MySQL database');
    connection.release();
  });

  return db;
};

module.exports = databaseConnection();

